# How to implement message passing in Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, message-passing

I have a file which overwrites `overlay.xul` that overwrites `browser.xul`. I want to implement message passing in a similar way as implemented in chrome extensions.

chrome.manifest-

```
content helloworld content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul    chrome://helloworld/content/overlay.xul
overlay chrome://navigator/content/navigator.xul    chrome://helloworld/content/overlay.xul


skin    helloworld  classic/1.0 skin/
style   chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul    chrome://helloworld/content/overlay.css
```

How to I register `content_script.js` which in my case is `overlay.js`?

Overlay.xul -

```
 <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://helloworld/content/jquery.js" />
 <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://helloworld/content/overlay.js" />
 <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://helloworld/content/background.js" />
```

Now inside my `overlay.js` I'm using -

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

     messageManager.sendAsyncMessage('MyMessenger.MyMessage', {});

}, true);
```

And the `background.js` is-

```
 addMessageListener("MyMessenger.MyMessage", function(obj) {

    Firebug.Console.log(obj.name);
}, true);
```

- What is the correct syntax for message passing?
- How do I configure the connection between content script and browser script?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are interested in is really injecting a content script and communicating with it then it should be easier to use the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder), particularly the [`page-mod` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html). It allows injecting content scripts easily and provides a way to communicate (see "Communicating With Content Scripts" section in the docs I mentioned).

As to `messageManager`, it is meant for a multi-process environment but it will work in the current single-process Firefox as well. The main problem with your code above is: `addMessageListener` isn't a global function, you should call `messageManager.addMessageListener()`. But using `messageManager` to pass messages between scripts that are loaded into the same namespace and could call each other directly is an overkill anyway.

To communicate with a content script in the current tab the script in the overlay would do:

```
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager.sendAsyncMessage('MyMessenger.MyMessage', {});
```

And the content script would indeed have `addMessageListener` as a global function so this should work:

```
addMessageListener("MyMessenger.MyMessage", function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.name);
});
```