# Calling a plug-in via an add-on

Tags: plugins, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, message-passing

**Scenario:**
I have developed an firefox add-on. I want my add-on to call another plug-in present in firefox.

**Problem:**
I am not able to figure it out how the plug-in can be called. In chrome, extensions can call plug-in by message passing. Can message passing can be used for firefox add-on.If it can be done can anyone provide guidance.
Following is the code:
Here is `main.js` file:

```
var {data} = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
include: "*",
attachTo: ["top"],
contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-2.1.0.js"),data.url("cwic.js"), data.url("my-  script.js")]
});
```

and Here is the `my_script.js` file:

```
//MAIN REGEX
var regex = /\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}/g; 

var text = $("body:first").html();

var textNodes = $("body:first").find('*').contents().filter(function(){

if(this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue) && this.parentElement.tagName !== "A"){
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    //alert(this.nodeValue.match(regex)[0]);
    //anchor.setAttribute('href', this.nodeValue);

    anchor.setAttribute('href', this.nodeValue.match(regex)[0]);

    anchor.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.nodeValue.match(regex)[0]));

    //alert(this.nodeValue.match(regex));


    if(this.nextSibling)
        this.parentElement.insertBefore(anchor, this.nextSibling);


    else
        this.parentElement.appendChild(anchor);


    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(regex, '');
}

return this.nodeType === 3;


});
$('a').click(function() {
    // When user clicks on the number it should call another plug-in to initiate    communication
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226042/how-to-implement-message-passing-in-firefox-extension

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the link. I have understood the concept behind message passing, but I am not able to figure it out as to how the plug-in can be called. Since, the add-on detects phone numbers on web-page, user clicks on the number to provide click to call functionality. Above is my code

Answer (score 0):

grab the window and use `chromeWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow.wrappedJSObject.$`

the wrappedJSObject gives you access to all the js in that window

Comment: I coudn't get what you mean to say ,since I am a beginner in developing add-on.Could you please ellaborate? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to put it in terms of addon sdk, maybe someone elese can help translate this to sdk.